# Send Data During Serial Port Data received Event

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am using COM4 Serial Port to both send and receive data. I have a demand request that comes in - I verify that the request is of mydatastring = myrequeststring - this works fine. I am trying to reply data through the com port during this event handler but of course Access is denied. How can I accomplish sending of data after receiving my request..??

```
    void scScale_OnReceiving(object sender, DataStreamEventArgs e)
    {
        if( e.Response == myrequeststring )
        {
            scScale.Transmit(this.data);
        }             
    }
```

**EDIT**

relevant parts of scScale - it is a SerialPort Client class - basically encapsulates the SerialPort details.

Relevant code:

```
public bool OpenConn()
{
    try
    {
        if (_serialPort == null)
            _serialPort = new SerialPort(_port, _baudRate, Parity.None);

        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = -1;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = -1;

            _serialPort.Open();

            if (_serialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                serThread.Start(); /*Start The Communication Thread*/
                IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsOpen = false;
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}


public void Transmit(string packet)
{
    _serialPort.Write(packet); // 0, packet.Length);
}

public void Transmit(byte[] packet)
{
    _serialPort.Write(packet, 0, packet.Length);
}
public int Receive(byte[] bytes, int offset, int count)
{
    int readBytes = 0;

    if (count > 0)
    {
        readBytes = _serialPort.Read(bytes, offset, count);
    }

    return readBytes;
}
    private void OnSerialReceiving(byte[] res)
    {
        if (OnReceiving != null)
        {
            OnReceiving(this, new DataStreamEventArgs(res));
        }
    }
```

SCSCALE is this code at link..
https://roofman.wordpress.com/2012/09/13/fast-serial-communication-for-c-real-time-applications/

Comment: Is the sender the serialport? If so why not cast it and use that instead?

Comment: What is scScale?  The standard windows serial port does not have a Transmit method.

Comment: @dbasnett - I added some relevant code - basically an encapsulation of the serial port.

Comment: @Peter4499 - a remote program sends a demand string via a com port. I read the connected com port. in my data received event - I read the data - determine if a request was made. If so I reply out of the same com port I never lose the connection as I need to be listening all the time. How does casting get me anything ? I have an Access denied exception - it is coming most likely because I am in the receive event of the serial port - it is not done - therefore I assume it is blocking.

Comment: @dbasnett I think I have found the problem - although very strange I subscribed to the event before the com port was open - the event fired and it did receive what I expected on the event ; but apparently sending it gave me access denied - weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why this works but it does; when the Serial Port was instantiated - I created the event handler and that did fire the event, but I was unable to send a reply through the port during handling of that event.
However if I subscribe to the event after the port is open, the event will fire and I will have access to the port to send a reply.

While I did not post my complete code - I do verify that the port is open before transmitting, and if not I open the port. 
Now instead of immediately subscribing to the receive event - I open the port and then subscribe to the OnReceive event.

The reason I changed the code to subscribe after the Port was open is because I was reading on SO and some other sites about strange behaviours caused by subscribing before the port was open.

So in short Subscribe to the receive event after the port is open.